# Decrypting HTTPS Traffic from Android Apps via Fiddler?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, https

I am actually trying to debug all the traffic going in and out on my phone. I am using Fiddler on my PC, and ProxyDroid on my phone to do this. HTTP traffic works fine. I am able to decrypt it completely. However, with HTTPS traffic, all I get is "Tunnel to : xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:443 ".
Any idea how do I decrypt the traffic going through the HTTPS route?

I installed the FiddlerRoot.cer on my phone through the default browser. Still no luck on decrypting the HTTPS traffic.

P.S : I am talking about traffic from apps, and not through the browser. My Phone is running ICS and is rooted.

Comment: Humm... I always thought the "S" in "HTTPS" stands for "secure". So the idea behind that is that you should *not* be able to easily decrypt it -- it is encrypted for good reason.

Comment: HTTPS is for protecting against a man in the middle attack... which is what it sounds like you're trying to do. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888884/can-https-connections-be-hijacked-with-a-man-in-the-middle-attack and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075489/preventing-man-in-the-middle-attack-while-using-https etc

Comment: Yes, I am exactly trying to do that. Using Fiddler, we can decrypt the HTTPS traffic. Read here --> http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/httpsdecryption.asp . Its easy to do this for browsers on the pc or phones etc. But I am trying to accomplish this for an App on my phone.

Comment: if the application is using custom trusted server certeficates , then no , you have to decompile the apk , crack it (disable that custom trust) then recompile it .. if the source is smali , search for "SecureRandom" on all smali files whene u find that word , u will find ur friend :D

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue.
First - make sure you have it all set up correctly on Fiddler on your PC:

1. Goto Tools-->Fiddler Options-->HTTPS and make sure the first 3 check boxes are   checked.
2. Click "Export Root Certificate to Desktop" and copy the cert file from your desktop to your device/SD card
3. In your device, goto setting-> security -> Credential Storage-> Install from SD Card , and install your certificate.

That's it.
worked for me :)

Comment: Not sure why it didn't work for me, but after another try I installed the fiddler root cert from  Fiddle Echo Service page http://ipv4.fiddler:8888/ (as described in docs http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/ConfigureForAndroid) and HTTPS traffic is decoded OK

Comment: Starting with Android 7.0/Nougat intercepting SSL traffic has become more complicated because the Android apps don't trust the installed additional system certificates unless the app developer explicitly has configured the app to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately modern Android does not trust the certificates generated by the built-in certificate generators, so we need a better certificate generator, luckily someone made one :)

- go to https://www.telerik.com/fiddler/add-ons and find the "CertMaker for iOS and Android" and download it and run it as administrator

[image]

[image]

- restart Fiddler
- go Tools -> Options -> HTTPS

[image]

ensure it says "Certificate generated by BCCertMaker.BCCertMaker from CertMaker.dll" (if not, re-run the CertMaker installer, and restart Fiddler again..), also make sure "Capture HTTPS" and "Decrypt HTTPS" is enabled

[image]

run "Reset all certificates" and wait for it to finish (this takes about a minute), then run "Export Root Certificate to Desktop"

[image]

Now move the FiddlerRoot.cer to your phone (doesn't matter how. [HFS](http://www.rejetto.com/hfs/) + your web browser is an alternative. Netcat and Termux is another alternative)

then on your Android go

- Settings -> Security -> Other Security Settings -> Credentials storage -> Install from device storage -> CA certificate -> FiddlerRoot.cer
- Settings -> Connections -> Wi-Fi -> the settings-button on your Wi-Fi -> View More -> Proxy -> Hostname to Fiddler computer's IP, proxy port 8888